# Most popular product

Tags: magento-1.7

I got free module from magento connect. Module name is **Ecommerceoffice_Mostpopular.xm**l. I have uploaded files in respective folder but it is not reflected in frontend.

Can anyone explain its logic and how it works?
  [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This extension you are using it creating based of **most_viewed_product**

you can look into his block for

**Ecommerceoffice/Mostpopular/Block/Home.php**

```
->setOrder('views_count', 'desc');
```

also the same product list will be shown in **admin/dashboard**. when you click on tab **Most Viewed Products**

Comment: Thanks -  admin/dashboard/MostViewedProducts - List is displayed in admin. But in frontend I cannot see anything.

Comment: @jassi i cannot guess what is problem maybe file is not your current may be any other issue as concern to you logic question this is the answer.